Conversion issues in sql - GREATEST(CEILING())
Below one working fine with the float values.
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect()
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT GREATEST(CEILING(Tot_Weight + 3.4),4.5) FROM TestTable order by id asc;')
print(cur.fetchall())

If I pass parameters to the query then facing conversion issues. Tried with str(Wt1) and str(Wt2) but no luck.
Wt1 = 7.02
Wt2 = 5.4
cur.execute('SELECT GREATEST(CEILING(Tot_Weight +'+ Wt1 +')', Wt2 +') FROM TestTable order by id asc;')
print(cur.fetchall())

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Please somebody help on this.

What language are you writing these calls in? Without knowing that, it's tricky to know how you're meant to pass parameters into your SQL calls but there almost certainly is a way, and it won't involve string concatenation. Please add a tag for your host language and, if applicable, what database technology within it that you're using.

python language

Right, and if I have to further guess, you're using mysql? If so, here's the documentation for the execute method that shows how to pass parameters into your query.

Are you using just SQL? Or an sql extention. also what does cur do. please provide more information. Would love to help!

updated my question.

This should work:
cur.execute('SELECT GREATEST(CEILING(Tot_Weight +' + str(Wt1) + '), ' + str(Wt2) +') FROM TestTable order by id asc;')

But a better way to do this is to use parameterized queries:
cur.execute('SELECT GREATEST(CEILING(Tot_Weight + ?), ?) FROM TestTable order by id asc;', (Wt1, Wt2))


The reason the 1 query is working fine is due to the reason that the whole query is written within the inverted comma which is the correct format to execute Mysql query in python .

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
